# How can I make Sum() return 0 instead of 'null'?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to use LINQ-to-entities to query my DB, where I have 3 tables: `Room`, `Conference`, and `Participant`.  Each room has many conferences, and each conference has many participants.  For each room, I'm trying to get a count of its conferences, and a sum of all of the participants for all of the room's conferences.  Here's my query:

```
var roomsData = context.Rooms
    .GroupJoin(
        context.Conferences
            .GroupJoin(
                context.Participants,
                conf => conf.Id,
                part => part.ConferenceId,
                (conf, parts) => new { Conference = conf, ParticipantCount = parts.Count() }
            ),
        rm => rm.Id,
        data => data.Conference.RoomId,
        (rm, confData) => new {
            Room = rm,
            ConferenceCount = confData.Count(),
            ParticipantCount = confData.Sum(cd => cd.ParticipantCount)
        }
    );
```

When I try and turn this into a list, I get the error:

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

I can fix this by changing the `Sum` line to:

```
ParticipantCount = confData.Count() == 0 ? 0 : confData.Sum(cd => cd.ParticipantCount)
```

But the trouble is that this seems to generate a more complex query and add 100ms onto the query time.  Is there a better way for me to tell EF that when it is summing `ParticipantCount`, an empty list for `confData` should just mean zero, rather than throwing an exception?  The annoying thing is that this error only happens with EF; if I create an empty in-memory `List<int>` and call `Sum()` on that, it gives me zero, rather than throwing an exception!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by changing the `Sum` line to:

```
ParticipantCount = (int?)confData.Sum(cd => cd.ParticipantCount)
```

Confusingly, it seems that even though IntelliSense tells me that the `int` overload for `Sum()` is getting used, at runtime it is actually using the `int?` overload because the `confData` list might be empty.  If I explicitly tell it the return type is `int?` it returns `null` for the empty list entries, and I can later null-coalesce the `null`s to zero.

Comment: I would suggest perhaps you could do `(int?)cd.ParticipantCount` and change `Sum` to return `int?`.

Comment: I would also suggest that this is a design flaw. `Enumerable.Sum<int>()` and `Enumerable.Sum<int?>()` return 0 for an empty sequence, so should `Queryable.Sum`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
 ParticipantCount = confData.DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(cd => cd.ParticipantCount)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, gives the exception `Unable to create a null constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.`.

Comment: does it work with the edited version? (without the null)

Comment: No, you're trying to default an anonymous type to zero.

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty()` should return the default value of the type, i thought?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the  [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) ?? as:

```
confData.Sum(cd => cd.ParticipantCount ?? 0)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the type of `ParticipantCount` is `int` so it can't be null-coalesced.

Comment: @Adrian the question clearly implies that ParticipantCount is an int? since the question is asking how to make Sum treat a null as a zero. So based on the information provided this is the correct answer to that question. However Jez says its just an int not an int? however in his own answer he is clearly casting ParticipantCount  to an int?.  Seems like the question isn't being asked correctly.

Comment: @RodneyS.Foley No, I think he should, but is not casting `ParticipantCount` in his own answer, and the null-coalescing operator isn't relevant since it is the return value of `Sum` that is `null`. Yeah, the title is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get EF to generate a SQL query that returns 0 instead of null, you change this as you process the query results on the client-side like this:

```
var results = from r in roomsData.AsEnumerable()
              select new 
              {
                r.Room,
                r.ConferenceCount,
                ParticipantCount = r.ParticipantCount ?? 0
              };
```

The `AsEnumerable()` forces the SQL query to be evaluated and the subsequent query operators are client-side LINQ-to-Objects.